# I want to create a class where the words for the ListView will come from. How i can make it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, listview

I want to create a class where the words for the ListView will come from.

Something like this, what I showed is not working, I did it like this for an example! How to connect them?
Like this:

> ListViewM.java

```
package great.biron.dargin;

public class ListViewM {


    private String mWords [] = {
            "Word1",
            "Word2"
    };

}
```

> Dictionary.java

```
//Variable start
private ListViewM mWords = new ListViewM();
//Variable end

//onCreate
myArrayList.add(mWords);
```

Comment: If `myArrayList` is an `ArrayList` then your `add` method won't work. I would create a method within `ListViewM` called `getList` that returns an `ArrayList`. Then in your `add` call you can pass in `mWords.getList()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class ListViewM {

 public static List<String> getWords() {
     return Arrays.asList("Word1", "Word2");
 };
}
```

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;  ?

Comment: Yes, import all necessary classes

Comment: How can I call this in Dictionary.java ?